# Encontrar mínimo en un array, en funcion de valores repetidos en las otras dos variables (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

Buenas,
Tengo un array organizado de la siguiente manera:

```
X   Y   Z
149 86  0
150 86  1
150 86  0
151 86  2
151 86  1
152 86  3
152 86  2
122 90  16
122 90  15
123 90  17
123 90  16
124 90  18
124 90  17
145 90  39
145 90  38
145 90  15
145 90  14
145 90  13
145 90  12
145 90  11
145 90  10
145 90  9
145 90  0
```

Y lo que me gustaría hacer es que MATLAB buscara los pares de valores X e Y repetidos, y para cada uno de esos pares, cogiera el menor valor de Z correspondiente. Es decir, por ejemplo, tomando el par X=150, Y=86, que MATLAB escribiera un nuevo vector que fuera 150, 86, 0, ya que los posibles valores de Z serían 0 o 1.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es encontrar todos los pares únicos de X y Y. La función `unique` tiene el parámetro `'rows'` que permite usar cada renglón como elemento individual:

```
u = unique([X Y],'rows')
```

Debe crear una matriz de tamano nx2, con n diferentes pares de valores. Ahora hay que buscar el menor valor de Z para cada par.

```
for i=1:length(u)       %Para cada par en u
    I_x = X==u(i,1);    %encuentra el indice de los valores en X que coinciden con el valor en u
    I_y = Y==u(i,2);    %encuentra el indice de los valores en Y que coinciden con el valor en u
    I = and(I_x,I_y);   %encuentra los indices en común entre ambos
    u(i,3)=min(Z(I));   %asigna el minimo valor de Z encontrado con estos indices
end
```